# Cannot get the HTML value of a dd element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help, I cannot get the html value of a dd element.

This is my code:

```
<table id="tabla_costo">
    <h2>
       Costo de Producción
    </h2>
    <dl>
        <dt>Codigo></dt>
        <dd class="code">
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt>Codigo Secundario></dt>
        <dd class="code2">
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt>Producto</dt>
        <dd class="name">
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt>Cantidad</dt>
        <dd class="quantity">
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt>Costo</dt>
        <dd class="cost">
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
    </dl>
</table>
```

I've tried this, but does not work:

```
var dl = $('#tabla_costo dl').find('dd.code').first().html();
console.log(dl);
```

But I'm getting undefined

This is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n96fvaoe/3/   (updated)

Comment: There's only one `dd.code` on your code, so using `first()` is useless. Remove the `.first()` part from your code and it should work as expected.

Comment: php scripting has no place in JS Fiddle, or in JavaScript questions (for the most part); please post the (minimal/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) HTML that's produced by that script, and include *that* HTML in your question, and up-date the linked demo. And please don't roll your question back to a version that's *harder to read.* The edit was intended to *help* you get an answer, which I presume is the result you'd prefer?

Comment: I'm still getting undefined https://jsfiddle.net/n96fvaoe/2/

Comment: Put all relevant information directly in the question so it's not dependent on off-site resources. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: @Servani: that would make absolutely no difference.

Comment: @squint: I put here "Please help, I cannot get the html value of a dd element.""so it's assumed I want to get the html value of the dd element

Comment: Yes, I know that. You didn't provide HTML in the question so we can't know what's wrong without visiting the link. Again, put all relevant information directly in the question so it's not dependent on off-site resources.

Comment: @squint: Ok no problem. I know that now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `<table>` has no rows or cells, so it's not a valid DOM structure.

If you change your `<table>` so that its content is in a cell:

```
<table id="tabla_costo">
<tr><td>
...content...
</td></tr>
</table>
```

it all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer from @RichieHindle, the only solution that would work here is the following.

```
var dl = $('dl').html();
```